# How to rotate multiple line on an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, line

I'm drawing diagonal lines across an image at regular spacing of around 70 pixels between them.

[image: Image describes what I would like to do]

Is there any possible way to do the rest?

I've done the central line but I'm struggling to do the rest. I've tried using a system using if and for loops and (I'll show the code below).

```
%------------------- Line through centre
aa=0;       %x1
ab=250;     %x2
a=[aa,ab];  %[x1,x2]

za=0;       %y1
zb=250;     %y2
n1=[za,zb];  %[y1,y2]

%------------------------ Line below centre
ba=50
bb=250
b=[ba,bb];

ya=0;
yb=200;
y=[ya,yb];

%Spacing between rotation
Rspac=5

slp=phantom(250);
imshow(slp);
set (gca,'xdir','normal');
set (gca,'ydir','normal');
axis on
hold on

%Plot for central diagonal line start
for x=Rspac*ones(1,(250/Rspac));
     aa=aa+x;
     ab=ab-x;
     line([aa,ab],[za,zb]);
end
     if aa==250;
         for z=Rspac*ones(1,250/Rspac);
             za=za+z;
             zb=zb-z;
             line([aa,ab],[za,zb]), 'r';
         end
    end

%Plot for line -50 and -100 from centre diagonal start
for n1=Rspac*ones(1,(250/Rspac));
    ba=ba+n1
    yb=yb+n1
    line([ba,bb],[ya,yb]);
    if yb>=250
        for n2=Rspac*ones(1,250/Rspac);
        ba=ba+n2;
        bb=bb-n2;
        line([ba,bb],[ya,yb]);
            if ba>=250
                for n3=Rspac*ones(1,250/Rspac);
                 bb=ba-n3
                 yb=yb+n3
                 line([ba,bb],[ya,yb]);
                    if bb>=250
                        for n4=Rspac*ones(1,250/Rspac);
                        ya=ya+n4
                        yb=bb-n4
                        line([ba,bb],[ya,yb]);
                            if ya>=250
                                for x=Rspac*ones(1,250/Rspac);
                                ba=ba-x
                                yb=yb-x
                                line([ba,bb],[ya,yb]);
                                    if yb<=0
                                        for x=Rspac*ones(1,250/Rspac);
                                        ba=ba-x
                                        bb=bb+x
                                        line([ba,bb],[ya,yb]);
                                        end
                                    end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I'm expecting to produce a line that rotates on its point around the image like the central diagonal line.

Comment: when you say "Do the rest". What exactly do you want to do. maybe if you can provide an image of what you have accomplished, and mark it up for what you would like to do, it would be more clear...

Comment: Hey, Ive just edited and included the image, sorry about being unclear

Comment: I think i see what you aim to achieve. I would need to study your code in pretty rigorous detail to see whats going on with that. Instead of that may I propose that you could write one single function to play a line, with a center location and a slope. Then use that function to plot all of the lines you need by passing in different inputs?? I'm not clear on why you have used so many boolean checks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's like one of many possible ways to do it, not using your data but you'll get the gist of it:

```
% line coordinates
x = [-1,1,nan];
y = [-1,1,nan];

% set up rotation matrix
nLine = 20;
theta = 2 * pi / nLine;
A = [cos(theta), sin(theta), 0;...
    -sin(theta), cos(theta), 0;...
     0,          0,          1];

hFig = figure; %figure handle
hL(1) = plot(x,y); % line object handle
hAx = hL(1).Parent; % axes handle

% make sputnik starburst things
for k = 2:nLine
    X = [hL.XData(end-2:end); hL.YData(end-2:end); ones(1,3)];
    Y = A * X;
    hL.XData = cat(2,hL.XData,Y(1,:));
    hL.YData = cat(2,hL.YData,Y(2,:));
end

% translate the starbursts
nStarburst = 4;
dx = 1:nStarburst; % horizontal step
dy = -dx; % vertical step
for k = 1:nStarburst
    hL(k+1) = copyobj(hL(1), hAx);
    hL(k+1).XData = hL(k+1).XData + dx(k);
    hL(k+1).YData = hL(k+1).YData + dy(k);
end
```

[walking starbursts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXLe3.png)

Comment: Hey, I think I get the gist of this! - Thank you!